# is there anyway to get datetime field in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format using formula field

Tags: apex, formula-field, datetime

How to get datetime field in format dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss format using formula field. I have date time as "9/12/2016 5:21 PM" but i want it as "12/9/2016 5:21 PM"

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

When you create a formula field, you would need to set it to return `DateTime`:

[image]

You'd need to explain in a bit more detail as to what your problem might be, but as you can see from the example there, you can use functions such as `NOW()` which would return the current `DateTime`.

The format that is returned depends on your [Locale Settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_getstart_what_format_is_used.htm&language=en&type=0).

> To find out what date/time format your Locale setting uses:
>
> 1. From your personal settings, enter Advanced User Details in the Quick Find box, then select Advanced User Details. No results? Enter Personal Information in the Quick Find box, then select Personal Information.
> 2. View the date/time format used in the read-only Created By field. This is the format you should use for entering dates and times in Salesforce fields.

If something like `M/D/Y H:M:S` is being returned instead of something like `D/M/Y H:M:S` and you'd prefer the latter, you can adjust the settings by going to...

> Setup > My Personal Information > Personal Information

... And adjusting the Locale setting there.

**Edit**

You could use a formula field to return a `String` (text) and use the following to construct your preferred `DateTime`:

```
MID(TEXT(NOW()), 9, 2) // Day
&"/"& // Add a slash
MID(TEXT(NOW()), 6, 2) // Month
&"/"& // Add a slash
MID(TEXT(NOW()), 0, 4) // Year
&" "& // Add a space
MID(TEXT(NOW()), 12, 5) // Get the whole time (hh:mm)
```

Basically here we're using the `MID` method to cut the `DateTime` based on their start position and how many characters we want to select. This will create `DD/MM/YYYY HH:MM`. Don't copy the comments into the formula.

Comment: i need it for email template. So i am using one datetime field but it is showing me as standard salesforce format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM. But i need it in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM so i am thinking to create a formula field for that.

Comment: @Jackvardy See my edits.